# MSBuild How do I copy files to build machine from network location?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I simply want to copy all the files and folders from a network location to the build location (where the script is run). The following runs without error but no files are copied.

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <FileRepositry>\\network_machine\c$\some_folder</FileRepositry>

  </PropertyGroup>
```

```
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyFileRepository">
    <Message Text="Copying file repository from $(FileRepositry)"/>
    <CreateItem Include="$(FileRepositry)\**\*.*">
      <Output ItemName="FileRepo" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FileRepo)"
          DestinationFiles="@(FileRepo-&gt;'C:\\FileRepository\\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <Message Text="Done." />
  </Target>
```

The source directory has two folders in it: Media and Source. I have created the folders at my build location -> c:\filerepository\media , c:\filerepository\source

The build runs and completes but the files are never copied over.

Can someone tell me what's up?

Comment: Is this target referenced anywhere?  Single backslashes in the DestinationFiles property I think.

Comment: Yes. I edited my question to show that. Thanks.

Comment: @(FileRepo-&gt; should be @(FileRepo->  In this case you won't want to escape the batching syntax (unless that's a copy/paste problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly permissions issue. Simply trying to access/copy files to this network revealed the problem. Adjusting the permissions at the source machine fixed this issue. Sorry for the bunk question.